# Error while connecting to Access database through Excel 2010

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve data from an access database on my C drive and i am getting the following error:

"Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user."

the debugger shows the error in the following piece of code:

```
MyConnObj.Open _
    "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\<database>.mdb;" & _
    "User ID=<username>;" & _
    "Password=<pass>;"
```

how do i fix this error?

I have the following definitions:

```
Dim MyConnObj As New ADODB.Connection 'ADODB Connection Object
Dim myRecSet As New ADODB.Recordset 'Recordset Object
Dim sqlStr As String ' String variable to store sql command
```

Comment: http://connectionstrings.com/access Best place to start with :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but that error means that you need to specify a Workgroup (system database) file.
Try to add this to your connection

```
MyConnObj.Open _ 
    "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _ 
    "Data Source=C:\<database>.mdb;" & _ 
    "Jet OLEDB:System Database=<path to system.mdw with information on username/pass>;" & _
    "User ID=<username>;" & _ 
    "Password=<pass>;"
```

in alternative, if your access mdb is not protected with a system.mdw file, you could try to remove the "User ID" and "Password" parts from the connection string.